# EF Update Two entities not updating in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to update `Applicant` and `ApplicantNotification` OneToOne relationship tables in the database. However, what I am trying is not working.

I select the objects via EF and then overwrite the properties, so I would assume EF will track the changes but doesn't reflect back in the database.

Question:
How to update two entities in EF?

Applicant:

```
[Index]
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ApplicantID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ApplicantTitle { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Address3 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CaseReference { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public ApplicantNotification Notification { get; set; }
```

ApplicantNotification:

```
[Index]
        [Key, Column("ApplicantID"), ForeignKey("Applicant")]
        public int ApplicantNotificationID { get; set; }
        public bool FirstNotification { get; set; }
        public bool SecondtNotification { get; set; }
        public bool ThirdNotification { get; set; }
        public bool FinalNotification { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? ReminderDate { get; set; }
        public int ReminderFrequency { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? FirstNotificationDate { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? SecondNotificationDate { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? ThirdNotificationDate { get; set; }
        public bool IsArchive { get; set; }
        public virtual Applicant Applicant { get; set; }
```

Method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(ApplicantNotificationViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //select from ef 
        var applicant = (from a in db.Applicants
                         where a.ApplicantID == model.ApplicantID
                         select a).FirstOrDefault();

        var applicantNotification = (from an in db.ApplicantNotifcations
                                     where an.ApplicantNotificationID == model.ApplicantID
                                     select an).FirstOrDefault();

        SetApplicant(model, applicant);
        SetApplicantNotification(model, applicantNotification);

        using (var context = new WorkSmartContext())
        {
                try
                {
                    db.Entry(applicant).State = EntityState.Modified;

                    db.Entry(applicantNotification).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    context.SaveChanges();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }

        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: no i have tried that too, doesn't update the table

Comment: Why the transaction in this scenario? EF will already wrap it in one. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456843(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: because, I am updating two entities? Assuming it would throw an exception on the second SaveChanges()? Also there is a OneToOne relationship between these two tables

Comment: the applicant variable is not null

Comment: Call SaveChanges() once. That's what makes it a transaction. Read my link.

Comment: Based on your suggestion, I have done this and still nothing is updated in db @SteveGreene

Comment: Sorry, I can not help you.

Comment: thank you for trying!!! :) @MatheusMiranda

Comment: Is that accurate code above? You are fetching from context called `db`, then you spawn off another context that it appears you don't use. You need to do all of the fetching and updating in a single context. Also, if it is truly 1:1, you should be able to use the navigation property on the principal to do the update.

Comment: Please see the update.

Comment: The one with `var context = new WorkSmartContext()`? No code is using that. You need to fetch and update using the same context instance.

Comment: ok let me try that

Comment: Duh! You are saving changes on that context. It knows nothing of the objects being tracked under db.

Comment: Change context.SaveChanges() to db.SaveChanges()

Comment: urgh!! duh! that's it. Well, as well as the noob mistake, I learned I can save two entities in a single SaveChanges method. Thanks!!

Comment: @SteveGreene can you elaborate on this a bit please "Also, if it is truly 1:1, you should be able to use the navigation property on the principal to do the update."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You look to be attempting to cross dbContexts or something, without seeing this WorkSmartContext definition it's hard to piece together but what you probably want is more like this:

```
var applicant = db.Applicants
  .Include(a=>a.Notification)
  .FirstOrDefault(a=>a.ApplicantId = model.ApplicantId);

if (applicant == null)
  // Handle missing Applicant scenario here.

SetApplicant(model, applicant);
SetNotification(model, applicant.Notification);

db.SaveChanges();
```

Your applicant has a reference to a related notification. Use it. You don't need to be loading individual related entities up. You can do things like checking for existing related entities, update them, insert if necessary, etc.  In cases where you need to update unrelated entities but ensure that all either succeed or fail, use a Transaction or a Unit of Work pattern. (which I'm guessing this WorkSmartContext is supposed to be, but without being derived from or tied to "db" I don't see how that is the case.)

Comment: awesome, was wondering how to use the navigation property to do exactly this